# Installing a package in docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, pip

I am using docker in django project, and installed packages which are in req.txt.
During project I needed to install a package and did it using `docker-compose exec web pip install 'package'` and `docker-compose up -d --build`, it installed in docker but I cannot use it in my project that not installed in project.
**Question:**

- How to install package in docker?
- Is it possible to write installed packages to req.txt using docker?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

    volumes:
      - .:/code

    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: That's the idea: you add the to `requirements.txt` and rebuild the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the standard workflow I'd use here.

First of all, make sure you have a normal working non-Docker development environment.

```sh
python3 -m venv vpy
. vpy/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

Then [edit your `setup.cfg` file to include the new package](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#declaring-required-dependency) and update the virtual environment.

```sh
$EDITOR setup.cfg
# add install_requires= package
pip install -e .
```

Make sure your application works properly.

```sh
pytest
run_the_app  # calling a setuptools console_scripts= script
```

Update the package lock file.

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

All of this so far is still on your host, outside of Docker.  Now you can rebuild the image to run integration tests:

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
curl http://localhost:8000
```

Note that this setup is the totally normal Python dependency workflow, plus a final "build your Docker image" at the end.  There is nothing Docker-specific in it, and you do not "install a dependency in Docker" or "update the host source code from the deployed image".  You could do a similar thing with newer tools like Pipenv instead of plain virtual environments.

(You do not need a Compose `volumes:` block to hide the code in the image, nor should you need a Compose `command:` line to override the Dockerfile's `CMD`.)